# What is a console based application?

Tags: java, console-application

My project was to create a console based application using java(I am using IntelliJ Idea, so I run my code and get inputs from user in their console and also show outputs to them there).I am storing my user's
data(my project is based on a hotel management system, so I save my user's account name and passwords)in a .txt file and access them using java. My question is I am creating a .txt file and store my user's data in my system because I thought if it is a console app we can't use other resources. Am I wrong? Can I use any database to store my user's data? They only said I need to create a console based app so I am not sure if I can use database. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "*I thought if it is a console app we can't use other resources. Am I wrong?*" Yes. Console app literally just means that you input/output text. There is no GUI. You could use a database. You could use a self-aware AI. You could use literally anything, provided you input and output text.

Comment: It usually only refers to the fact that your program has no GUI (other than the console). Doesnt matter what the program does, as long as it has no GUI. Often it will have command line arguments, interpret them and maybe output something, but does not have to.

Answer (score 1):

Console applications really just means that the output and user input takes place from the console, as opposed to a GUI.

There isn't really a restriction inherit from the term "Console application" that says you can't store data in a text file or a database.